# Does the quantum mechanical wave function work as a charge distribution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

The quantum mechanical wave function is traditionally interpreted as a probability distribution of the particles position. It is possible to interact with an electron in a conductor, without collapsing the wave function, which can be distributed over the entire conductor. Can the wave function be understood as a charge distribution in this case? And if so, wouldn’t that mean that the particle actually takes the shape of the wave function?

Comment: It has been pointed out many times before that "collapse of the wave function" is not a useful physical terminology. Moreover, most physical interactions with metals (like a conductivity measurement) are not going to show any quantum mechanical effects. Those are completely covered up by ordinary thermodynamics. Even if you get to a quantum mechanical effect in a metal, it will have to be described by a many-body theory, which does not show the trivial single-quantum effects that you are probably expecting.

Answer (score 3):

The charge distribution is related to the probability of the electron being in a given location. That is, the amplitude-squared of the wave fucnction, $\bar{\psi}  \psi $.

Under some circumstances this can work as a charge distribution. For example, in an atom the charge distribution is given that way, including the nucleus.

The interaction between some other particle and an electron in a conductor is going to be with the wave function, not the charge distribution. So, if the other thing is a photon, there will be some sort of $A \psi$ type interaction. That is, it will sample the wave function, not specifically the charge distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You state that the wave function under some circumstances can work as a charge distribution. Under which circumstances will it not be so? 

And if electron flies by a conductor and interacts magnetically or electrically, I would say that this is an interaction with the charge distribution. Thats what i had in mind. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Schrödinger initially believed that the wave function is related to actual charge distribution density, rather than to probability density. Some objections were raised to such interpretation. One of the objections is based on wave packet dispersion. I offered some modification of the interpretation ([Entropy 2022, 24(2), 261](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/24/2/261)), where it is assumed that the wave function is related to coarse-grained charge density, and one-particle wave functions are modeled as plasma-like collections of a large number of particles and antiparticles. This modification seems to be immune to the problem of wave packet dispersion.